# How do i take the first number of values in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What i'm trying to achieve is to take the first 23 values of an array (to become **array B**) that contains 92 values (**Array A**) and put those 23 values into their own array. But it must *literally* take the first 23 values so **Array A** will be left with 69 values. Then i'm able to take another 23 values and but them into their own array (Array C) and so on...

For a small scale example:

**Take 3 values from Array A**

```
[ 320,
  272,
  412,
  36,
  36,
  36,
  31,
  30,
  30,
  387,
  338,
  511]
```

to become...
**Array B**

```
[ 320,
272,
412]
```

**Array A with 9 values**

```
[36,
  36,
  36,
  31,
  30,
  30,
  387,
  338,
  511]
```

I've tried lodash `_.take` but it doesn't literally *take* the values from the array since it leaves it in the array.

Comment: Seems that you already know how to create array B. Now you just have to remove the first n values from array A. That should be easily googleable.

Comment: Have you looked into any array function yet? If not have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype

Comment: Array.splice is the one you are searching for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
let a = [ 320,
  272,
  412,
  36,
  36,
  36,
  31,
  30,
  30,
  387,
  338,
  511];
  
  let b = a.splice(0, 3);
  console.log(b);
  console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using lodash, you can use [`_.remove`](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#remove):

```js
var A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var B = _.remove(A, function(value, index, array) {
  return index < 3;
});    
console.log(B);
console.log(A);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
var arrayB = arrayA.slice(1, 24);
arrayA = arrayA.slice(24, 93);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why destroy the original array? That will be provably quite slow. Ypu could turn your array into a 2d one:

```
var arr = Array(500).fill(230);//whatever input
var result = [], chunk = 23;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length - chunk +1; i+= chunk)
  result.push( arr.slice(i, i + chunk) );
```

So the result looks like this:

```
[
[...23],
[...23]
...
]
```

To take the first 23 do

```
result[0]
```

...and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1- using splice method-

```
 let array1 = [ 320,
  272,
  412,
  36,
  36,
  36,
  31,
  30,
  30,
  387,
  338,
  511];

    var array2 = array1.splice(0, a.indexOf(412));
```

To remove '412' from array2:

```
array2.shift();

Method 2-

Using Lo-dash
For Example-
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var p1 = _.first(ar, 4); 
var p2 = _.rest(ar, 4);
```

Method 3- 
use splice as above

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
y = x.splice(3);
console.log(x); // [1,2,3]
console.log(y.shift()); // [4,5,6]
```